# Ошибка database is locked

Tags: python, sql

Есть бот который парсит посты с сообществ Вконтакте и отправляет их в тг канал.
Подключена база данных, имеется функция `update_status` Она отвечает за обновление статуса после того как пост отправился в канал. При обновления статуса происходит ошибка `database is locked`. Из ошибки я понял что SQL3 пытается одновременно выполнить несколько изменений в таблице, поэтому происходит блокировка.

Хэндлер бота где происходит отправка постов и их обновление:
Ошибку показывает в строчке `update_status()`

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands=["Pars"])
async def cmd_pars(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Начал процесс сбора данных")

    while True:
        post_date() 
        res = select_res()
        for x in res:
            rest = '\n'.join(x)
            if len(rest) < 400:

                await bot.send_message(chat_id=-ЧАТ_ID, text=rest)
                time.sleep(3)
            update_status()

        await asyncio.sleep(60)
```

Функция запроса SQL:
Ошибка возникает в `return update()`

```py
# Обновляем статус
def update_status():
    with sq.connect("data_pars.db") as db:
        cur = db.cursor()

        update = cur.execute("UPDATE vk_post SET status=True")
        db.commit()
        return update
```

Пробовал убирать `db.commit()` в запросе, удалял полностью бд, не могу понять как они конкурируют между собой.

Ошибка:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-9' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\тг бот тест\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=OperationalError('database is locked')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\тг бот тест\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\тг бот тест\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\тг бот тест\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\тг бот тест\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\тг бот тест\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\тг бот тест\Парсер вк групп\bot_pars_vk.py", line 37, in cmd_pars
    update_status()
  File "C:\тг бот тест\Парсер вк групп\sqlite.py", line 41, in update_status
    db.commit()
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
```

Comment: А что, у вас в таблице `vk_post` одна запись всего реально? Или наоборот там миллион записей и вы их все одновременно обновляете? У вас же запрос без условия. А вообще лучше приведите ошибку целиком в вопросе, прямо все строки трейса.

Comment: не забываем закрывать курсор

Comment: Кстати, да, `cursor` тоже лучше через `with` открывать, если правильно помню

Comment: @CrazyElf Записей много

Comment: @KARL А зачем вы обновляете все записи в базе? Разве там не должно быть привязки к конкретной какой-то сущности?

Comment: @CrazyElf Изначально статус False после отправки поста в канал, статус обновляется на True

Comment: @CrazyElf Бот отправляет только посты со статусом False чтобы не приходили одни и те же посты

Comment: @CrazyElf Бот работал неделю корректно без ошибок

Comment: `return update` попробуйте вытащить из оператора `with`.

Comment: @СергейКох Это ничего не должно поменять. `with` эквивалентен `try/finally`, выход из менеджера всё-равно выполнится при выходе из блока кода, `return` ему никак не помешает, ему вообще ничего не может помешать, ну, разве что если сам питон упадёт.

Comment: @CrazyElf, а у курсора в sqlite разве предусмотрена конструкция `with`? Я конечно сейчас еще раз попробую, но если память не изменяет, то оно там так не работает. Само соединение - пожалуйста, а вот с курсором в этом плане были проблемы.

Comment: @Namerek Тут, кстати, вроде не указано, какой модуль используется для работы с БД. А от используемого модуля вполне может зависеть есть ли там `with` для курсора.

Comment: @Namerek Модуль sqlite3 установлен, до этого бот работал целую неделю без ошибок. Сейчас выдает данную ошибку. Куда посмотреть и что исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему
Вынес функцию `update_status()` из if блока

```
    @dp.message_handler(commands=["Pars"])
async def cmd_pars(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Начал процесс сбора данных")

    while True:
        post_date() 
        res = select_res()
        for x in res:
            rest = '\n'.join(x)
            if len(rest) < 400:

                await bot.send_message(chat_id=-ЧАТ_ID, text=rest)
                time.sleep(3)
        update_status() 

        await asyncio.sleep(60)
```